# How to match cv2.imread to the keras image.img_load output

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing, keras

I'm studying deep learning. Trained an image classification algorithm. The problem is, however, that to train images I used:

```
test_image = image.load_img('some.png', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
```

While for actual application I use:

```
test_image = cv2.imread('trick.png')
test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (64, 64))
```

But I found that those give a different ndarray (different data):

Last entries from load_image:

```
  [ 64.  71.  66.]
  [ 64.  71.  66.]
  [ 62.  69.  67.]]]
```

Last entries from cv2.imread:

```
  [ 15  23  27]
  [ 16  24  28]
  [ 14  24  28]]]
```

, so the system is not working. Is there a way to match results of one to another?

Comment: Different how? Different shape, data?

Comment: @nuric Udpdated question

Comment: `image.load_img()` uses `PIL` which reads in `RGB` while `cv2.imread()` reads in `BGR`. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OpenCV reads images in BGR format whereas in keras, it is represented in RGB.  To get the OpenCV version to correspond to the order we expect (RGB), simply reverse the channels:

```
test_image = cv2.imread('trick.png')
test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (64, 64))
test_image = test_image[...,::-1] # Added
```

The last line reverses the channels to be in RGB order.  You can then feed this into your keras model.

Another point I'd like to add is that `cv2.imread` usually reads in images in `uint8` precision.  Examining the output of your keras loaded image, you can see that the data is in floating point precision so you may also want to convert to a floating-point representation, such as `float32`:

```
import numpy as np
# ...
# ...
test_image = test_image[...,::-1].astype(np.float32)
```

As a final point, depending on how you trained your model it's usually customary to normalize the image pixel values to a `[0,1]` range.  If you did this with your keras model, make sure you divide your values by 255 in your image read in through OpenCV:

```
import numpy as np
# ...
# ...
test_image = (test_image[...,::-1].astype(np.float32)) / 255.0
```

Comment: @JeruLuke :D I've never heard that expression before.  The closest I've heard is with the use of birds, but mangoes works too :)

Answer (score 8):

Recently, I came across the same issue. I tried to convert the color channel and resize the image with OpenCV. However, PIL and OpenCV have very different ways of image resizing. 
Here is the exact solution to this problem.

This is the function that takes **image file path** , convert to targeted size and prepares for the Keras model -

```
import cv2
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from PIL import Image

def prepare_image (file):
    im_resized = image.load_img(file, target_size = (224,224))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(im_resized)
    image_array_expanded = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis = 0)
    return keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(image_array_expanded)

# execute the function
PIL_image = prepare_image ("lena.png")
```

If you have an OpenCV image then the function will be like this -

```
def prepare_image2 (img):
    # convert the color from BGR to RGB then convert to PIL array
    cvt_image =  cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im_pil = Image.fromarray(cvt_image)

    # resize the array (image) then PIL image
    im_resized = im_pil.resize((224, 224))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(im_resized)
    image_array_expanded = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis = 0)
    return keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(image_array_expanded)

# execute the function
img = cv2.imread("lena.png")
cv2_image = prepare_image2 (img)

# finally check if it is working  
np.array_equal(PIL_image, cv2_image)
>> True
```

Comment: Yes of course since you're using a pretrained network so you need to use their preprocessing methods. Also take note that you're using MobileNetV2. You should expand your answer to generalize to any pretrained network.

Comment: good solution, but I got "'str' object has no attribute 'img_to_array'", so the solution is
{
img_ = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(im_resized)

img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img_)
}

Answer (score 5):

Besides CV2 using the BGR format and Keras (using PIL as a backend) using the RGB format, there are also significant differences in the resize methods of CV2 and PIL using the same parameters.

Multiple references can be found on the internet but the general idea is that there are subtle differences in pixel coordinate systems used in the two resize algorithms and also potential issues with different methods of casting to float as an intermediate step in the interpolation algo. End result is a visually similar image but one that is slightly shifted/perturbed between versions.

A perfect example of an adversarial attack that can cause huge differences in accuracy despite small input differences.